# Not Returning Array .get()

Tags: jquery, arrays

Hi I'm a bit new to ajax and jquery. 
I'm trying to pass an Array from PHP file to my main page with the javascript.
So far it is returning an html string.

Would appreciate any help on what is the correct way to do this.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
var results;
j( document ).ready(function() {
    j.get("tool_processor.php", {
      key: "value"
    })
    .done(function (data){
      var options = j(data).find('response').first().text();


      if (options instanceof Array) {
        alert('value is Array!');
        } else {
        alert('Not an array');
        }

    });
});
```

and the php file

```
$arr= array('one', 'two', 'three');
return($arr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use data returned form php as array, you can encode your array as json and iterate through returned data like;

**PHP:**

```
$arr= array('one', 'two', 'three');
return json_encode($arr);
```

**JS:**

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
var results;
j( document ).ready(function() {
    j.get("tool_processor.php", {
      key: "value"
    })
    .done(function (data){
      $.each(data, function(k,v) {
          console.log(v); // one, two, tree
       });

    });
});
```

Comment: Tried fixing it and modifying. I get no returns. But I get your idea.

Comment: Check your php log. Also, if you open php error_log level, you can see errors returned

Comment: I added `var data = JSON.parse(data);` to parse the data into an array but I keep getting Unexpected end of Input. at the line

Comment: It means, you have not json data returned. Go to your php url on browser and see what is returned. Also you can check it on firebug

Comment: Managed to fix it by changing return to echo the json.

Answer (score 0):

options cannot be an Array as it is a String the .text() returns a String.

If the text is well formated : `['a', 'b', 'c']` , you can use `var array = JSON.parse(string)`

Answer (score 0):

In your `tool_processor.php` file , please return data as JSON.

Then you can use data as JSON type then access by object

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
var results;
j( document ).ready(function() {
    j.get("tool_processor.php", {
      key: "value"
    })
    .done(function (data){
      var data = JSON.parse(data);
      // Process data JSON 
    });
});
```

Tutorials about [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)